# How to fix Object is possibly 'undefined' TS 2532 issue? Code attached below

Tags: typescript, google-maps

```
    147 |               const values = {
    148 |                 coords: {
  > 149 |                   lat: res.geometry.location.lat(),
        |                        ^
    150 |                   lng: res.geometry.location.lng(),
    151 |                 },
    152 |                 address,
```

The problem text:

(property) google.maps.places.PlaceGeometry.location?: google.maps.LatLng | undefined
The Place’s position.

Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: What is unclear? You're accessing a property that could be undefined, and trying to call methods on it - what _do_ you want to happen if it is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

it means exactly what it says, the value you are trying to pass to the object might be undefined, what you can do is check if its undefined using javascript's [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) before passing the item e.g:

```
const values = {
  coords: {
    lat: res.geometry.location.lat() ?? defaultLat,
    lng: res.geometry.location.lng() ?? defaultLng,
  },
  address
}
```

or you can use typescripts [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) by appending "!" to the value name (only use this if you are sure that the value cant be null or undefined)

```
const values = {
  coords: {
    lat: res.geometry.location.lat()!,
    lng: res.geometry.location.lng()!,
  },
  address
}
```